Replacing a deleted Landsat 5 dataset in Google Earth Engine 'LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1' for 2012 NDVI calculation
I'm trying to calculate NDVI for 2012 within my study area in GEE. I believe the best available quality is Landsat 5, and when I'm trying to filter the Image Collection with this function:
"var landsatCollection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1')", a notification pops up that it's a deleted Landsat dataset.
This is my entire code:
// Filter the image collection based on region and date range
var Filtered_Region = ImageCollection.filterBounds(Region);
var startDate = '2012-04-01';
var endDate = '2012-05-15';

// Function to calculate NDVI for Landsat 5 images
function calculateNDVI(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B4', 'B3']).rename('NDVI'); // B4: NIR, B3: Red
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
}

// Filter Landsat 5 image collection for the given date range and region
var landsatCollection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T1')
  .filterBounds(Region)
  .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
  .map(calculateNDVI);

// Get the median NDVI image over the date range
var medianNDVI = landsatCollection.select('NDVI').median();

// Define visualization parameters
var visParams = {
  min: -1,
  max: 1,
  palette: ['blue', 'white', 'green']
};

// Add the NDVI layer to the map with a custom name
Map.addLayer(medianNDVI, visParams, 'NDVI 2012');

// Print the NDVI image to the console for additional information
print('Median NDVI Image:', medianNDVI);

I've tried changing it to 'LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T1_L2' or 'LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T1', but these appear not to be working (the layer has no bands to visualise).

The Landsat Collection 1 is deprecated and it is recommended to use Collection 2 as mentioned here.
The Landsat 5 image collections end around May 2012. For your date range, only a part of the Earth has imagery available (midwestern and western US). I am unable to attach the screenshot here unfortunately.
So I would suggest the next best option, which is to go with the Landsat 7 image collection, if that satisfies your selection criteria.
